# Deprecation of the modern-in-medieval tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

After a dicussion in WB chat, we decided to perform a tag cleanup/restructuring on the [modern-in-medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-in-medieval) tag. (@MonicaCellio said it was okay) It was originally added in early April 2015 but has not been used since then.  This tag was removed in an effort to clean up the tag space and remove precedent for the proliferation of tags like [modern-in-rome](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-in-rome) or [modern-in-babylon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-in-babylon).

Most of the changes were just rollbacks but a few took editing to remove the tag.

Comment: Nice work Green.

Comment: Thanks for doing this.